# Properly use preg_match?

Tags: php, .htaccess, match

How would I change the following preg_match() code to also block the index.html file, stead of only '.' , '..' , or '.htaccess'?

```
preg_match('/^\.(htaccess|\.)?/',$file)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
preg_match('/^(\.(htaccess|\.)?|index\.html)/',$file)
```

However, regular expressions are not necessary here

```
in_array($file, array('.', '..', '.htaccess', 'index.html'))
```

More readable and easier to extend :)

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like:

```
preg_match('/^(\.(htaccess|\.)?)|(index\.html)/',$file)
```

By the way, the parenthesis are just for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `preg_match('/^\.(htaccess|\.)?/',$file)` blocks also any other file beginning with a `.` (because of the `?`). So KingCrunch's second solution is not the same and can be risky!

So when you want to match any file starting with a dot (so also including `.htaccess` and `..`) and `index.html` you could use:

`preg_match('/^(\.|index\.html)/',$file)`